# Firewalling Virtual Machines

Tags: virtualization, firewall, virtual-machines

I am setting up a VM of Win Vista to use for testing purposes.  If I am running a firewall on the host computer, does the host firewall filter all traffic before it gets to the virtual NIC in the VM, thus protecting it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends. If you setup the Virtual Machine to use NAT, it does. If you set it to bridged networking, it does not (this is VMWare terminology, but others have the same thing).

You could have provided us with the name of the virtualization solution you use.

Comment: While I agree with most of what you wrote, in regard to your last paragraph, system administration is not just about server operating systems. Supporting workstations is a normal part of an admin's job.

Comment: What happens if the host machine has firewall rules for the bridge?

Comment: I do my testing on my own workstation, a MacBook Pro (10.5.8 OS X), using VMware Fusion.  I just checked and there is a bridged option and a NAT option, so I will opt for NAT.  Thanks guys!

Comment: @sybreon:
actually, I don't know. Maybe you want to ask that as a question of its own?

@John: you are probably right, I should have read the FAQ, removed it.